# Alternative of Functions for Data Retrieval from Table with Always Encrypted Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core

I am currently working on a project where I need to add Always Encrypted feature of SQL Server to a few columns of particular tables. But I am having trouble doing that because those table's related SQL Function cannot be refreshed with updated encrypted metadata of table. That is happening due to the fact that the SQL Functions return temporary tables with unencrypted column which correspond to the encrypted column of a table. One such example of a function would be like this where LastName column is encrypted -

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestApplicantFunc 
(
   @Id [bigint]
)
RETURNS 
@TestTable TABLE 
(
   LastName [nvarchar](32)
)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @TestTable(LastName)

   SELECT a.LastName FROM dbo.EncryptedTable as a
   WHERE a.ID = @Id
   RETURN 
END
GO
```

Now this type of functions have been used in multiple places which is difficult to locate. So, is there anything I can do and still keep the Function definitions as there might be a lot of breaking changes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for simply can't be done.
If it could be done, it would violate the main principle of the always-encrypted feature - which is the separation of the encryption / decryption of the data from the database itself.

From the [Always Encrypted (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) documentation:

> Always Encrypted allows clients to encrypt sensitive data inside client applications and never reveal the encryption keys to the Database Engine ( SQL Database or SQL Server). As a result, Always Encrypted provides a separation between those who own the data (and can view it) and those who manage the data (but should have no access). By ensuring on-premises database administrators, cloud database operators, or other high-privileged, but unauthorized users, cannot access the encrypted data, Always Encrypted enables customers to confidently store sensitive data outside of their direct control.

However, you can find where the function is used simply by selecting from the built-in table valued function [`sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.TestApplicantFunc', 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a way I did not see before to get references.